# How to turn Dymola package.order warnings into error

Tags: data-structures, modelica

Dymola sometimes shows warnings about incorrect package.order (either class found but not listed in package.order, or class listed in package.order but not found on disk).
In the end, package.order is duplicate information anyway.
That warning is displayed when opening a library, but not when checking or compiling a model.

[image]

Is there a way to turn that into an error, instead of warning, to be used in regression testing?
Is there a button/function to let the Dymola fix the package.order file?

Comment: The best solution I can think of is to create a function which checks that the package.order matches the .mo files in that directory, throughout a library. Unfortunately I could not find a way to automatically run a function on loading a library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `Advanced.PedanticModelica=true;` before loading the library to turn the warning into error.

However, it is not guaranteed that message is given when opening the library - (using a scripting function or File>Open>Load) - since classes are normally demand-loaded and if the error is deep down in the hierarchy it may be detected later.

You can set `Advanced.UI.DemandLoadClasses=0;` (before loading) to get immediate feedback on the problem even in that case, but it will slow down loading the library.

Comment: And will investigate if it can also be reported during check, without being too annoying.

Comment: Thank you Hans! I also tried to submit a bug report, because I believe the warning is incorrect for the case that a class is listed in the package.order file but does not exist on disk.

Comment: Thx, I don't think that is a bug - but it may be that it is unclear: A class in package.order should either be stored directly in package.mo or as a separate file/directory in the directory.